# Python Transform this function into a recursive one

Tags: python, function, recursion

I'm having some difficulties getting my head around recursive functions.
I have this function that I would like to transform into a recursive one.
can you help me out? what is the reasoning behind your code?

Normal function:

```
def sum(arg):
    result = 0
    for i in arg:
        result += i
    return result
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def recursive_sum(arg):
    return arg[0] + recursive_sum(arg[1:]) if arg else 0
```

The task of summing can be reduced to one of two actions:

- If the `arg` is not an empty list, then the sum is equal to the first element of `arg` + the sum of all the elements of the same `arg` without the first element i.e. `arg[1:]`. But this second term can be obtained by applying `recursive_sum` to the new `arg` as well!
- If the `arg` is an empty list, then the sum is clearly zero. This is called a *base case*. It's when your recursion *terminates*.

You can see how this works with the following list:

```
recursive_sum([1,2,3,4,5]) 
-> 1 + recursive_sum([2,3,4,5]) 
-> 1 + (2 + recursive_sum([3,4,5])) 
-> ... 
-> 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + recursive_sum([])
-> 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + 0
= 15
```

---

Note that doing `arg[1:]` is an example of [list splicing](http://pythoncentral.io/how-to-slice-listsarrays-and-tuples-in-python/), which lets you get a new list with everything except the first element, and you can test if a list is empty by just doing `if list`.